# Implementing a SAML 2.0 Service Provider using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I wanted to implement a Spring Boot SAML2.0 service provider. This service provider doesn't need to communicate to IDP as it will only receive an assertion object. My questions are:

1. How can I implement a spring boot SAML2.0 service provider that only accept assertion objects. Get the principal information and redirect to a web application url with the information in the body?
2. What is Assertion Consumer Service URL? How can I provide it with the created SP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved my problem by creating a full SAML service provider using spring SAML extension. I was not knowledgeable with SAML service provider so I thought I could just create a code that would expose ACS URL and that's it. I configured the ACS url by setting up the SP base entity url and configured SAML Web SSO Processing filter.

Comment: will it be possible to share the code for setting up the ACS in spring boot

Comment: You can check the code here https://github.com/zorlac/XamSAMLServiceProvider

Answer (score 1):

If you only process a SAML Assertion, then you are not really implementing a SAMLv2 compliant Service Provider. A Service Provider does far more. Spring Security SAML extension is a Service Provider which could be used for your use case. The Assertion Consumer URL is configurable in Spring Boot configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I only need to process SAML assertion is because our company is using Siteminder and the requirements only needs an ACS url and the service provider who will consume the assertions. Siteminder takes care of loging part, we only need to send the fcc version of our login screen

Comment: The ACS is the URL where you want the SAML Response to be sent to, so it will be the endpoint you configured to perform the actual login flow

Comment: @Bernhard Thalmayer: Could you share a code snippet of your configuration in Spring as well as the .yml files? That would be really helpful, thank you